# Insert Hebrew text to SQL databse table ( Codeigniter)

Tags: php, sql-server-2012, codeigniter-3

- I am using php codeigniter with database SQL. I am having problems while inserting hebrew text into table. The text gets converted to question marks and some other special characters.

**I have set my database collation to : Hebrew_CI_AS**

Also i have added this code on the head section of view pages

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Please let me the possible solution for it.

Comment: Their is a tutorial on [this link](http://giladlotan.com/2008/01/displaying-hebrew-characters-with-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

If your database collation is **utf8_general_ci** (this is what I normally use) it should display correctly in the table.

In addition to the code you have in the head section, I have also used the [HTML lang attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_lang.asp) for specific HTML elements in past projects:

```
<p lang='he'> Some Hebrew text. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> While working on this mini-project I’ve realized that there is hardly any online tutorials on using the Hebrew font. Here’s my solution which is fairly simple and works effectively.
>
> - Set the HTML page charset encoding to utf8:

```
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8“>
```

> - set the ‘collation’ attribute for the fields which are to accept hebrew text to: utf8_bin
> - within your php script, right before calling the mysql_query function to insert the data into your DB, use both the utf8_encode function along with addslashes. This will encode the data into utf8 friendly characters.
> - when pulling the text from the DB onto the page, make sure to use the utf8_decode along with stripslashes in order to display the data on the page.

as @Perrykipkerrie says. this is a good tutorial.